# iOS 13 How to hide UISearchController searchBar in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, ios13

I have navigation bar with search bar (UISearchController) 
I have left bar button icon that when clicked shows this search controller by assigning it to navigationItem like so:

```
if navigationItem.searchController != nil {
            navigationItem.searchController = nil
            navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
            navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        } else {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
            navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
```

It works but then if on cancel button touch I try to hide search bar then I have view controller dismissed and black screen appears (no view controllers)

```
extension SearchableMenuViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard #available(iOS 11.0, *) else { return }
        guard !isAlwaysVisible else { return }

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
                self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        } else {
            navigationItem.searchController = nil
            navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
            navigationController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

I have tried to add delay cause not removing this searchcontroller from navigationItem animates it to extended navigation bar with Title + Search Controller and then tapping Search icon properly hides search controller. So the problem is I think removing search controller while it is animating to extended navigation bar

Answer (score 4):

Super lame haxx that will solve your issue temporarily:

```
func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {

        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = nil

            self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.navigationController?.view.layoutSubviews()

            let view = UIView()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.insertSubview(view, at: 1)
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }      
    }
```